# How can i dynamically set the number of rows based on the value of an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, coldfusion

I am trying to set the number of rows containing form fields based on the value of an input box. How can I accomplish this? Code snippet below. Basically I want to loop the value in the "numpos" field. Ideally I'd like to have it dynamically update when the user types a number in the numpos field.

```
<tr>
  <th>Number Of Positions:</th>
  <td colspan="4"><cfinput type="text" name="numpos" required="yes" message="Please enter the number of positions"></td>
</tr>
<cfif #mynum# NEQ 0>
  <cfloop from="1" to="#mynum#" index="i">
    <tr>
      <th>Number Of People Needed:</th>
      <th>Position Description:</th>
      <th>Date:</th>
      <th>Start Time:</th>
      <th>End Time:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><cfinput type="text" name="numpeople"></td>
      <td><cfinput type="text" name="posdesc"></td>
      <td><cfinput type="text" name="posdate"></td>
      <td><cfinput type="text" name="starttime"></td>
      <td><cfinput type="text" name="endtime"></td>
    </tr>
  </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Remember - ColdFusion runs on the server. If you don't know the number of positions while processing on the server then you can't use ColdFusion to do it. _Unless_ you post back to the server with every input. Not a really good user experience. That leaves you with using client side JavaScript. You indicated jQuery in your tags. There are LOTS of jQuery examples for what you are doing. [Here is one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-table-rows-using-jquery/)

Comment: Since you'll be using jQuery, use plain html `input`'s instead of `cfinput` so you're not mixing two different event models.  Also, nothing to do with the question, but no need for pound signs in statements like this `<cfif #mynum# NEQ 0>`.